# Why date comes with value a day ago?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, momentjs, angular-moment

Help with the problem. For 2 days I can’t understand what the problem is. I am using the Angular component "Datepicker that uses Moment.js dates". But the problem is that when I select for example 03/10/2015, the component returns 03/09/2015. I understand that this is due to the time zone, since I have (UTC + 3), but I do not understand how to solve it.

My code component.html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="datepicker" *ngIf="buttonDisabled" >
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="birthdate" [value]="user.birthdate" formControlName="birthdate" >
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="birthdate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #birthdate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';

import * as _moment from 'moment';
import { default as _rollupMoment } from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

@Component({
  selector: 'userinfo',
  templateUrl: './userinfo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../../app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS }
  ]
})

export class UserInfoComponent {

  mgForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    "birthdate": new FormControl(moment(this.user.birthdate)),
  });
```

Comment: why about using `moment.utc` method https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Comment: @Kenny Already tried nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the offset time of date as given below:

`dt.setTime(dt.getTime() - (dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));`

Answer (score 0):

Try using angular's date pipe - formatDate()

`{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}`

Docs are here - https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
moment().toISOString();
moment().toISOString(keepOffset);
```

`.toISOString()` returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in  local mode.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/